# Chrome does not follow its own locale in a date input element

Tags: html, date, input, locale

When I test the code I found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date

```
<input type="date" id="start" name="trip-start" value="2018-07-22" min="2018-01-01" max="2018-12-31" />
```

I always see the widget rendered with a US locale (mm/dd/yyy):

[image]

The same page says:

> [...] the displayed date is formatted based on the locale of the user's browser [...]

even though, my browser's locale is set to Dutch:

[image]

How can I get the date-input's locale to use Dutch (dd-mm-yyyy) ?

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Comment: @Rob, this question is specifically about how something is rendered and browser settings. Posting code will not convey my question correctly.

Comment: @Rob, No you are not *required* to post an MRE, from https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask: "Not all questions benefit from including code, but if your problem is with code you've written, you should include some."

Comment: Then why are you linking to, and posting, code?

Comment: @Rob I added the minor snippet of code. But the point is the way it is rendered.

Comment: So the code is needed to reproduce the problem, right?

Comment: It's a small line of HTML, I don't think we need to enforce rules this strictly.

Answer (score 0):

Dutch has to be the default "appearance" language for it to work correspondingly, otherwise it won't.

### Settings

Under `chrome://settings/languages`

"Preferred language", add Dutch, and mark in the "Display Google Chrome in this language".

As seen here:

[image]

Then it asks you to restart, then it should look like this:

[image]

And on that this will work:

```html
<input type="date" id="start" name="trip-start" value="2018-07-22" min="2018-01-01" max="2018-12-31" />
```

...like this:

[image]

Comment: I do not have that option .... this is my version information: `Version 119.0.6045.199 (Official Build) (64-bit)` Running on Fedora Linux.

Comment: May not help but I see the options on `119.0.6045.200 (Official Build) (64-bit) (cohort: Stable)`

Comment: @BartFriederichs try this: settings > languages > preferred languages, click the dots near  Dutch, and check "show google chrome in this language". (I'm back-translating here to English, so the wording might be slightly different)

Comment: @TsahiAsher that option is not there. I guess my Chrome install is a little weird.